# actionscript remove (concat?) sub-arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, concatenation, arrays

I have multiple sub-arrays in one huge array - MasterArray- meaning that the sub-arrays are already INSIDE the MasterArray. I would like to "fuse" all of those sub-arrays - to remove those [ ] square brackets.

I would like to avoid the "concat" method because the arrays are already inside the MasterArray. Is there a command/method how to do this?
Thank you.

```
var englandCities:Array = [London, Manchester, Leeds];
var franceCities:Array = [Paris, Orleans, Avignon];

var europeanCities:Array = [englandCities, franceCities];
```

I would like to point let's say...to "London" nested in the europeanCities array somehow.
After I try to trace it, it gives me "englandCities", which makes sense.

```
trace(europeanCities[0]);
// displays "englandCities"
// how can I make it display "London" ?
```

How can I make the europeanCities array to display "London" ?
I NEED TO REMOVE THOSE SQUARE BRACES from the "europeanCities" array WITHOUT using the concat() thingie...

OKAY let me rephrase this a bit. My master array:

```
var europeanCities:Array = [englandCities, franceCities];
```

equals to

```
[[London, Manchester, Leeds], [Paris, Orleans, Avignon]];
```

am I right? And now, how to remove the inner brackets in order to get something like this:

```
[London, Manchester, Leeds, Paris, Orleans, Avignon];
```

And please, keep in mind, that the array is much longer than englandCities and frenchCities....there are like...30 different Cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` those together easily, and it really is the simplest option:

```
var englandCities:Array = ["London", "Manchester", "Leeds"];
var frenchCities:Array = ["Paris", "Orleans", "Avignon"];
var masterArray:Array = [englandCities, frenchCities];

var europeanCities:Array = new Array();

for each(var country:Array in masterArray) {
    europeanCities = europeanCities.concat(country);
}

trace(europeanCities); // London,Manchester,Leeds,Paris,Orleans,Avignon
```

I'm not sure I understand your reason for avoiding `concat` for this, unless the issue is it that you don't want to duplicate the values. (So modifying `englandCities[0]` will also modify `europeanCities[0]`.)

If your cities are `Objects` rather than primitive `String`s, a concatenated `Array` will work fine. If they are primitives though, there's no way to do this with an `Array`. You could however write a *function* to provide similar behaviour like this:

```
var englandCities:Array = ["London", "Manchester", "Leeds"];
var frenchCities:Array = ["Paris", "Orleans", "Avignon"];
var allCities:Array = [englandCities, frenchCities];

function europeanCities(id:int):String {
    var cityID:uint = 0;
    while (id > allCities[cityID].length - 1) {
        id -= allCities[cityID].length;
        cityID++;
    }
    return allCities[cityID][id];
}

trace (europeanCities(0)); // London
trace (europeanCities(5)); // Avignon
```

Comment: okay so do you all think that concat is the best thing to do? If yes I will probably try and do that...I wanted to avoid it because my code already contains over 100 arrays...but then again...one more array wouldn't hurt, right..?  :)

Comment: Yes, it is kind of an odd thing to worry about. I've edited my answer with a simple concat loop.

Comment: thanks David. I used the "for each" trick combined with concat method and somehow it's worked! since I'm an AS3 beginner, I don't quite understand that "while" stuff. but the point is it works :)  cheers bro :)

Comment: Great! The `while` part checks if the id is too high to be in the first group of cities, then steps through them until it finds the right group. If that's sorted out everything, you can click the tick to accept answers and mark your question as solved (and get a little bonus rep). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty array, then traverse the `masterArray` taking any sub-arrays, and do a `concat()` for your new array. This will make you another array that's flat, without disturbing master array.

Comment: but the point I was trying to make is to AVOID the "concat"  :) any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to display `europeanCities[0][0]`?

Comment: +1 for this... @user1832012 What is wrong with concat? Concat into new array then make europeanCities = yourNewArray;

Answer (score 1):

I just write this here because it is possible.

If you insist on not using concat here is one bad solution:

```
 // join elements into a comma delimited string
 var s: String = europeanCities.join(','); 
 // Split the string with delimiter as commas
 europeanCities = s.split(',');
```

Since the subarray elements automatically will be joined with ',' regardless of join delimiter and our join delimiter is already ',' this will work.

But this solution is cpu intensive and not optimal.

Comment: thanks for the advice..I think I will go with the concat method after all :)